# Different button different context menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, contextmenu

i have four button and on that four button i want to call different context menu, this is working for the first button,how to implement the same type of code to the other three. I also tried to add another button and include other context menu int the same override method, also checked the websites, so please tell me how to do it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.semtosub);
    sub1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subject1);
    registerForContextMenu(sub1);   

}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.contexts1,menu);

}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.chapter1:
        Intent c1 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C1.class);
           startActivity(c1);
           break;

    case R.id.chapter2:
        Intent c2 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C2.class);
           startActivity(c2);
           break;
    case R.id.chapter3:
        Intent c3 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C3.class);
           startActivity(c3);
           break;   
    case R.id.chapter4:
        Intent c4 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C4.class);
           startActivity(c4);
           break;       
    case R.id.chapter5:
        Intent c5 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C5.class);
           startActivity(c5);
           break; 
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

}

}

Comment: Clear your question first...

Comment: As far as I know, you can only have one active activity at any given time. I think you're best placing your two lists in 2 fragments within a single activity and then starting that activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Run two or many activity on one button click?

Use [Context.startActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities%28android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle%29) which take multiple intents in Array and start Activity one-by-one:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i_one = new Intent (Semester.this,Subject.class); 
        Intent j_two = new Intent (Semester.this,Subject2.class);
        startActivities(new Intent[]{i_one,j_two}); 

    }
```

Comment: @prosper K I am new to android so can you please tell me where to and how to add the Context.startActivities..?

Comment: @PuneetKushwah:  In `onClick` add my suggested code

Comment: @PuneetKushwah: have you declared all activities with `<category 
                android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` category ? and let me know what happening on button click

Comment: no i just wrote "Intent c1 = new Intent(Subject.this,Sub1C1.class);
            startActivity(c1);"

Comment: @PuneetKushwah: why you are not using my suggest code? please remove all code from `onClick` and try to use only my suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68078/discussion-between-puneet-kushwah-and--k).